# How can I generate this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a `list`, such as `[3, 2, 4]`, how can I generate the following output?

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 4]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 4]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 4]
[1, 0, 0]
...
[1, 2, 4]
...
[3, 2, 4]
```

I need to generate every list possible where each element of the list is positive and is not greater than the number given at the relevant index.

I know this involves `for` loops, but I'm looking for the most efficient way (probably using a generator) which can deal with lists of varying sizes.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be more specific? What is it that needs to be done?

Comment: What's the logic behind the output? Also, please add your code and tell us what's the problem with your code?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Kasramvd I need to generate every list possible where each element of the list is positive and is not greater than the number given at the relevant index.

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with some ranges!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can do the job:

```
from itertools import product
l = [3,2,4]
print(*product(*[range(i+1) for i in l]), sep='\n')
```

would print:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 4)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(0, 2, 3)
(0, 2, 4)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
...
(3, 2, 3)
(3, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

`[[x, y, z] for x in range(3+1) for y in range(2+1) for z in range(4+1)]` is what you are looking for.

edit: Not your solution if you have a variable number of elements in your input.

Comment: Can this be generalised? (as my list has a variable number of elements)